# how to get domain url in initializer file, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer, domain-name

i was wondering if it was possible to get the domain url ie

```
localhost or myapp.heroku.com
```

from an initializer file?

i believe the

```
request.url
```

and the request methods only work in controllers. is there an equivalent to the javascript

```
document.domain
```

that i could do in an initializer file? or could i embed the .rb file with javascript?
or other alternatives to the request object?

ive tried a number of things that don't work such as

```
Rails.root
```

and am having trouble trying to figure it out.

thank you = )

Comment: Can you write what you want to achieve so we could suggest an laternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just changed one of my apps to a staging environment. i couldn't get the socket to work.

```
heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=staging --app myapp-staging
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --app myapp-staging
```

and then i made a staging.rb file inside my environments folder (i just copied and pasted everything from my production file) and rails was able to infer the method

```
Rails.env.staging?
```

in my initializer

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the original question at all. You marked your own answer correct because it's a work around- not the solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
require 'socket'

Socket.gethostname
```

Comment: hmm i when i try that, i get a bunch of random numbers like

45b636d4-2820-481b-bf44-d2546bb804fe

Answer (score 1):

Your application is only able to determine it's domain when serving a request. (Thus it's available for controllers in `request`.) In an initializer, which is executed once, on startup, before any requests get served, it isn't possible. (Unless you, the maintainer, know the domain in advance and specify it in configuration, e.g. in an environment variable.)

It is even possible for a single application to run on several domains. Then every request may have a different domain.